# php code to increment date on every loop runs

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my coupon column data is present like this  500,501,502 OK..

There are 3 values in coupon column so i am inserting 3 rows in database with every coupon value..

I need to insert coupondate is also an increment order of months in every loop runs...suppose above loop runs 3 times then 3 coupondate to be inserted in coupondate column.

thats it...thats why i used loop there ...

Please help to resolve my problem.
I need every date to be inserted in database not last one.

```
$coupon = $_POST['coupon'];                     
                            $arr = explode(",", $coupon);
                            $min = min($arr);
                            $max = max($arr);
                            $startingdate = $_POST['startingdate'];                         
                            for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++)
                            {                       
                             $coupondate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate)) . " +" . $i .  "month")); 
                            for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++)
                            {               
                $insertrow  = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO book_issue (coupondate,coupon) VALUES (:coupondate,:coupon)", array(':coupondate'=>$coupondate,':coupon'=>$i));
           }
}
```

Comment: I see there are a lot of questions coming through all related to dates, books, receipts and coupons. I'm guessing they are all related to a college course of some form so I assume that the tutor recommended StackOverflow as a good source of information but neglected to tell their students that it's not a "Coders 4 Free" site

Comment: why you have any problem with question...if you think this forum created for only you ...then you are wrong men...do your job...not interfere to other....

Comment: The question is not the problem. The fact that there has been a glut of them over the past few weeks is. All use the same DB access functions, all have the DB schema, all show a "That's solved. How do I do the next bit?" transition etc. The main thing is, if you come to SO for every little problem you hit, you're never going to develop your problem solving skills. Personally, I think dev work is 80% problem solving, 10% putting that into practice. and 10% adding bits around the outside to make it work a bit better

Comment: thaks sir you are correct....i know i am taking help in every level of problem......next time i remember this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$coupon = $_POST['coupon'];                     
$arr = explode(",", $coupon);
$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);
$startingdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['startingdate']));
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= count($arr) ; $i++) {
    $count = 1;
    for ($ii = $min; $ii <= $max; $ii++) {
        $coupondate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate)) . " +" . $count . " month"));
        $count++;
        $insertrow  = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO book_issue (coupondate) VALUES (:coupondate)", array(':coupondate'=>$coupondate));
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the code to work now, you don't put it inside an insert clause in the loop, but after it.

Comment: Are you sure you used the latest edit of the code? I noticed that also earlier, and fixed a moment ago. Using database queries inside a loop is kind of a bad practice in my opinion. Do you need all the dates (26-03-2015, 26-04-2015 and 26-05-2015) in the database or just the coupon expiration date, which would be the last one of them, because if you need just the latest date, you won't need the query inside the loop.

Comment: Updated my answer. You still have this line wrong in your code: `$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . $i .  "1MONTHS"));` change it to match and then you will get the correct dates.

Comment: sir i change my post there plz read my complete scenario there and tell the code accordingly...i know you are facing problem in understanding what i want.....but your code is not working in my scenarion....plz ..plz

Comment: Edited again :) Indeed I'm having hard time understanding the end-result. Hope that I'm getting close :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code you missed the incrementing month value

```
for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    $dates[] = $coupon . " - " . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . $i . " MONTHS -1 DAYS"));        
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($dates); //out put you required
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

OOP way:

```
$startingdate = '26-02-2015';
$date = new DateTime($startingdate);
$diff = new DateInterval('P1M');
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $date->add($diff);
    print_r($date);
}
```

[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$startingdate = '26-02-2015';

$min = 0;
$max = 2;

for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    $dates[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . ($i+1) . " MONTHS"));        
}


var_dump($dates);
```

Comment: for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) { $dates[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . $i . MONTHS")); $coupondate = $dates; $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO book_issue (coupondate) VALUES (:coupondate)", array(':coupondate'=>$coupondate)); }